# Storing linkages between tables

Tags: database, database-design

I'm building an app that works on two databases -- **own_db** and **external_db**.

**own_db** has tables entities and attributes for all tables and columns in **external_db** respectively.

**external_db** has tables which are linked to each other for example *employee* can have a *department* etc. This linkage can be through a third table called *external_db.link_employee_department*.

Now **own_db** needs to preserve this linkage information for later use.

How do I storing this information? I guess there can be n number of linkage tables in between.

Ideas?

Comment: You say **own_db** has tables and columns for everything in **external_db**.  Does this not include intersection tables such as `link_employee_department`?  Also, what is the relationship between these two databases.  Do they share data as well as structure?  All data or just a sub-set?  Do they need to be kept in sync?  All the time or just periodically?  Is one database a master and the other a slave?  Do you want `own_db.employees` to have a foreign key which references `external_db.departments`? In short, *what is the actual concern here*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a data integration / application integration requirement. You could consider using an integration / middleware platform. These usually have repositories that can manage exactly this kind of source to target mapping with lineage tracking, impact analysis, versioning, etc. Some examples are: Oracle Fusion, IBM InfoSphere, Informatica, Ab Initio.